# How do I launch a new instance of RAD Studio from Explorer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have the habit of opening my Delphi projects from File Explorer by double-clicking on the .dpr or .dproj file.

Normally, this will launch Embarcadero RAD Studio XE7 in my case and open the project for me.

I'd like to compare how something is done in a separate project (different directory, etc.). If I double-click on a second .dpr/.dproj file, the default action seems to be to add that to the Project Group of the instance of RAD Studio that I already have open.

Is there a way I can set up RAD Studio to open a second instance for me so that I can see things side by side?

Currently I manually open up a new instance and then find the project file through File->Open, but that is painful.

Comment: Opening a new instance is easy. Hard to see past that.

Comment: Drag the dpr to the IDE.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Drag the dpr to *the new instance of* the IDE. Just be aware that dragging a dpr onto the IDE will still add the dpr to the current project group if there is one, so you have to make sure there is no project being auto-loaded in the new IDE instance (auto-saved workspace, etc) before dragging.

Comment: You can try using the [Delphi Dev. Shell Tools](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-dev-shell-tools/) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Registry, the `.dpr` and `.dproj` file extensions are registered to invoke `bdslauncher.exe` if the IDE is not already running, and to invoke DDE to pass the dragged filename to an existing IDE if it is running.  So, the only way to make a double-click open a new instance of the IDE would be to change the Registry settings to bypass `bdslauncher.exe` and DDE and just invoke `bds.exe` directly with the filename as a command-line parameter.

Otherwise, the other alternatives are to:

1. drag&drop a `.dpr`/`.droj` file directly onto the `bds.exe` file, which will run a new copy of `bds.exe` that will open the dragged file.

[image: drag and drop]

2. right-click on a `.dpr`/`.dproj` file, choose "Open With", and select `bds.exe` (you can optionally set it as the default app or not).  On subsequent right-clicks, the "Open With" menu will now have a submenu (if it did not already) that includes "Embarcadero RAD Studio" as an option.

[image: open with]

Comment: It's a lot easier to accomplish than that. If you right click and choose "Open With", you can change the default application that launches it from BDSLauncher.exe to bds.exe without having to play with the registry editor.

Comment: I would not suggest changing the default app (and btw, a file's default app can be changed in the Control Panel as well).  However, using the "Open With" option would add bds.exe as an available option to a submenu on "Open With" for subsequent right-clicks, so then you can use "Open With > Embarcadero RAD Studio" to open the file in bds.exe directly.

Comment: Noted. Is there a negative to changing the default app that I've missed?

Comment: Another aproach that you can use is create a "Send To" shortcut which actually points to "bds.exe". The best thing about this approach is that you can use it for any supported file and you don't have to select "bds.exe" as default application for opening specific delphi files. This also alows you to retain default double click fiunctionality.

Comment: That would essentially do the same thing as the "Open With" approach when unchecking the "Always use the selected program" checkbox in the select dialog.  Two right-click menu items doing the same thing. The only difference being that one is stored in the Registry and applies to specific file types, the other is a shortcut created within `%APPDATA%` and applies to all files unconditionally.

Comment: Another feature about using of "Send to" shortcut that I forgot to mention is the ability for your to also specify custom parameters like switches etc.